# How do I specify which cygwin drive to use?

Tags: cygwin, installation

I have Cygwin installed on 2 different drives (not sure why!) C and D

C is full proper version I want

D is some sort of copy.

BUT Cygwin appears to default to D. I know this because it uses the .bashrc from D not the C one.

Where do I tell Cygwin that I want it to point at the C version? Without reinstalling everything?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would all depend upon how you are starting your shell. Likely you are starting it by opening a shortcut to something called "Cygwin Terminal" or possibly "Cygwin64 Terminal". If you look at the properties of the shortcut, you can see which one it is invoking. If you want to invoke a different one, change the drive letters and path in the shortcut properties.

As an aside, having two installations of Cygwin, even on two different drives, is almost certainly a bad idea. You can have multiple installations if you know what you're doing, but it's not recommended.